# Why does this throw Null Pointer Exception?

Tags: java

My code :

```
static List<Object> data;
private void addItem(List<Object> list) {
    try {
        data = new ArrayList<Object>();
        list.add("test");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();        
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ListTest test = new ListTest();
    test.addItem(data);
}
```

Above code throws `NullPointerException`. The code below does not throw NPE.

```
static List<Object> data = new Vector<Object>();
private void addItem(List<Object> list) {
    try {
        list.add("test");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();        
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ListTest test = new ListTest();
    test.addItem(data);
}
```

Above code does not throw `NullPointerException`. I don't understand the difference between both.

Comment: `static ... data` isn't initialized in 1st case, so it got default `null` value, and you get an NPE.

Comment: Because http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value

Comment: NullPointerException - look for a `.` or a `[` after a variable not properly set.

Comment: In the first snippet the method `void addItem` expects a `List<Object>`, but instead it gets a null pointer, namely `data` which has not been initialized so it is null.

In the second snippet it gets an initialized vector.

What is the confusion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though you passed `data` reference to the method, the moment you assign a new list to `data`:

```
data = new ArrayList<Object>();
```

`list` and `data` reference are now pointing to 2 different objects. Before that assignment, `data` was set to `null` and so was `list`. But after the assignment, only `list` is set to `null`. And thus calling `list.add()` will result in `NPE`.

In second case, `data` was not `null` to begin with.